# sliding divs from bottom to top

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to slide divs from bottom to top. I have 3 divs. In that first two will be visible,

on click:

```
1st div get hides.
2nd div takes 1st div position.
3rd div takes 2nd div position.
```

again on click:

```
2nd div get hides.
3rd div takes 2nd div position 
1st div takes 3rd div position.
```

Check this:- http://jsfiddle.net/2cz5v/5/

Working for 3 clicks, then it starts interchanging the divs. Please Help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the initial positions of your divs and set them in an array, and then just had your click function animate between those initial positions.

```
    var places = [
    {
        top: $('#div1').offset().top, //100,
        left: $('#div1').offset().left, //100,
        width: $('#div1').width(), //80,
        height: $('#div1').height(), //30,
        opacity: 100
    },
    {
        top: $('#div2').offset().top, //200,
        left: $('#div2').offset().left, //100,
        width: $('#div2').width(), //80,
        height: $('#div2').height(), //30,
        opacity: 100
    },
    {
        top: $('#div3').offset().top, //300,
        left: $('#div3').offset().left, //100,
        width: $('#div3').width(), //80,
        height: $('#div3').height(), //30,
        opacity: 0
    }
];
```

And then later on in the update statement

```
    $("#div"+j).animate({top: places[0].top, left: places[0].left, height: places[0].height, width: places[0].width, opacity: places[0].opacity}, 1000);
    $("#div"+k).animate({top: places[1].top, left: places[1].left, height: places[1].height, width: places[1].width, opacity: places[1].opacity}, 1000);
    $("#div"+l).animate({top: places[2].top, left: places[2].left, height: places[2].height, width: places[2].width, opacity: places[2].opacity}, 1000);
```

Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DTM3J/2/)

Answer (score 1):

you can rotate the classes in combination with [CSS3 transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/) for a fairly simple solution

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cz5v/20/)

HTML:

```
<div id="div1" class="rotate firstdiv">div #1</div>
<div id="div2" class="rotate seconddiv">div #2</div>
<div id="div3" class="rotate thirddiv">div #3</div>                
<button id="moveitButton">move it!</button>​
```

CSS:

```
...
.rotate {
    -webkit-transition:all .5s;
    -moz-transition:all .5s;
    -o-transition:all .5s;
    -ms-transition:all .5s;
    transition:all .5s;
}
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
var $rotateDivs = $('.rotate');

$("#moveitButton").click(function() {
    $rotateDivs.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.hasClass('firstdiv')) {
            $this.removeClass('firstdiv').addClass('thirddiv');
        } else if ($this.hasClass('seconddiv')) {
            $this.removeClass('seconddiv').addClass('firstdiv');
        } else if ($this.hasClass('thirddiv')) {
            $this.removeClass('thirddiv').addClass('seconddiv');            
        }
    });
});
```

note: IE 10+ supports CSS3 transitions - http://caniuse.com/#search=transitions

Comment: You rock, for a fairly simple solution using css3, but my intention is to support all the old browser too. Thanks for the reply.